# Deploy aplicação usando --prod e estratégia de caminho

Tags: node.js, angular, deploy

Estou tentando fazer deploy de aplicação angular 8

Quando uso o comando

```
ng build --prod --base-href /app/
```

Quando tento executar a aplicação no localhost/app

A aplicação não carrega

No console tem essa mensagem:

> http://localhost/app/main-es2015.de53c17ebee928a1e2c9.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Mas quando faço o deploy sem o `--prod` ela roda a aplicação, porém, se eu atualizar a página, o servidor não encontra a página

Só posso atualizar a página se eu fizer o deploy usando a estratégia de Hash

```
providers: [
    //{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy} //adicionar um # a url
  ]
```

[Edit]

Estou usando o servidor Apache 2.4

O meu arquivo .htaccess dentro da pasta app (localhost/app) está assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Conforme documentação

Comment: que servidor vc ta usando?

Comment: Usei o servidor Apache 2.4

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml da uma olhada nessa configuração do seu htaccess, isso pelo menos vai fazer que quando se atualiza ele não perca a pagina

Comment: Foi daí que eu peguei a configuração

Comment: tenta RewriteRule ^ /app/index.html

Comment: Deu certo, amigo! Isso mesmo. .htacess, agora falta o --prod

Comment: Deu isso aqui: `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` quando usei o `--prod`

Comment: Tenta ver se esse arquivo que ele esta buscando realmente existe no servidor e o caminho está correto

Comment: Quando faço deploy sem `--prod` a aplicação roda normal... Para disponibilizar a aplicação com o endereço da api produção, tenho que mudar o endereço no `environment` sendo que já está configurada no `environment.prod`

Comment: @EduardoVargas coloque sua resposta sobre o .htaccess que eu vou atrás de resolver sobre o deploy com `--prod`.. Você Já ajudou muito